# Xamarin layout designer view not working properly

Tags: android, layout, xamarin

I am working on visual studio for android development on Xamarin platform. I am facing a weird issue. If I make some changes in my .axml file 2-3 times, the designer vie stops working. It keeps on loading but do not show anything. I have to restart my visual studio as admin to check the design. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug I believe in the current version of Xamarin. Most users have downgraded to 4.1.2 to fix this issue.

See this post: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/77992/axml-layout-designer-inside-visual-studio-keeps-loading-forever